# NPM wont work because of my wrong node version

Tags: installation, apt, 13.04, nodejs

The error is:

Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.5.11-pre
Required: node@>=0.6

But I'v just updated my node. That is confusing.

I'v made some digging and it seems that I've installed node two times

node version is v0.5.11-pre (node -v)

and

my nodejs version is v0.10.5 (nodejs -v)

When I check the usr/bin there is a link named 'node' and there is a application named 'nodejs'. The link points to /etc/alternatives/node link and this link points back to usr/bin/nodejs application.

I 'whereis' to the nodejs and node. These are output:

```
whereis node: 
/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/X11/node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz

whereis nodejs:

/usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/nodejs /usr/bin/X11/nodejs /usr/include/nodejs /usr/share/nodejs /usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz
```

**EDIT1:**

I've also tried 
apt-get remove node
and 
apt-get remove nodejs

Intrestingly when I tried node command it still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing [`update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/update-alternatives.8.html) like the following might help:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node nodejs /usr/bin/nodejs 100

$ node -v
v0.10.7
```

Maybe delete all alternatives to node before:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all nodejs
```

Comment: thanx for the usefull tips.

Comment: I get an error: "update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/node is already managed by node". I've ensured the "node" package (something entirely unrelated to do with modems) is uninstalled and purged, and nodejs is installed.

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config node` resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that I'v installed an old version (v0.5.11-pre) as well to my local/bin.

When I try to remove the node with `apt-get remove` command it removes the latest install version that installed via apt-get (v0.10)

I removed the folders

```
/etc/local/bin/node/
```

and

```
/etc/local/lib/node/
```

This solved the conflict.

Comment: `I removed the files and solved` which files exactly? Can you explain it in bit detail for future reference. Thank you!

Comment: @BasharatSial detail added